# Writing Simple Crypto using Different Passwords for Encrypting/Decrypting

Tags: java, encryption

I am posed with a problem which I have no idea how to solve, essentially I have these Files which one may enter a "write" or "read" password (these passwords are different), and I need to Encrypt and Decrypt these files using a common algorithm such as AES.

I know how to use crypto libraries (I will be using the ones provided in Java), however, I am unsure how to make this secure, or how to implement this.

I originally thought of storing salted hashes of these passwords for write/read, and then checking the entered password, however, I am unsure how the Crypto would work, if I have a keystore in say Java, won't it need a password so the keys don't appear in plaintext; I cannot have the keystore password in plaintext anywhere and I am not allowed to just make one up. Is there any well known solution to this problem I am positing which I can study?

Essentially: is there anyway to get access to encrypting or decrypting using a key derived from read/write passwords DEPENDING on the type of password entered, i.e. a user entering a READ password cannot encrypt, just decrypt.

Comment: This just a course assignment or the like, I hope...

Comment: Yeah, it it, I am trying to make heads or tails out of my design from the spec he assigned us

Answer (score 0):

Public-key cryptography has two separate keys, one to decrypt, one to encrypt. Usually, one of the two is public, though. In your case, you'd want to keep both private, and protect them with your two passwords. I suppose that would work for RSA (where the public key cannot be derived from the private key, which in other schemes it could).

So you'd be creating an RSA keypair, and store the two keys separately, protected with the two passphrases. That way you can control access to them individually.

Comment: I like the idea as I replied below, but I'd need to store pairs of keys per each user in the system? This design seems so convoluted for something that is only worth 1/3 * 0.2 of a 10 credit module. I might be misinterpreting the spec

Answer (score 0):

Use RSA encryption to encrypt and decrypt an AES key. Use the AES key to encrypt and decrypt the content file.

The Java `Keystore` API doesn't support encryption of public key entries, but it does encourage the use of a password to protect the integrity of public keys. Your application could be written to use the "encryption" password to load a key store with the "public" encryption key, and fail if the wrong password is entered. Of course, a user can circumvent this outside the application, and get access to the public key using something like `keytool` or their own custom code. But you can't really stop someone from performing encryption with some key; why do you care if they use this key?

Private key entries would be encrypted with the "decryption" password. This common use case is well supported by the `Keystore` API.

Comment: I like the idea, but what if multiple passwords are acceptable to access a encryption or decryption password. I'd need multiple keypairs to implement that right per password on the system.

Comment: @Display You could do it with multiple key pairs, or you could duplicate an RSA key in different private key entries with different password, and public key in keystores with different passwords. Normally, though, each user has a private key, and one password to protect that private decryption key and any public keys they might use for encryption. If one file needs to be readable by multiple people, you'd encrypt its AES key with the public key of each reader.

Comment: @Display encryption of one key with another is standard. It's how CMS (S/MIME), PGP, other common crypto systems work. There's nothing "convoluted" about it. The weird thing in your assignment is the bizarre requirement to keep the encryption key private. Normally, you want to be able to authenticate the encryption key, so that you don't encrypt a file with the attacker's key instead of the intended recipient.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not allowed to store the key(s) elsewhere, I would store them in the encrypted file.  I would encrypt the file with AES and then encrypt that key (the "file-key") twice by two AES keys (read-key and write-key and store:

```
[length-of-next-section] [file-key-encrypted-by-read] [length] [file-key-encrypted-by-write-key] [length] [file-data-as-encrypted-by-file-key]
```

FWIW, this is akin to how MAC OS X's "File Vault 2" whole disk encryption works -- the disk encrypted with a key, and 1 or more people's passwords are used to encrypt that key, thus any of these person's passwords can be used to "unlock" the disk at boot time.

Comment: Hey, this is a fantastic suggestion, however there's just one thing I am missing, say a Write user encrypts a file, so that the [write] section is different from the [read] when in plain-text. So when the [read] user tries to read the file, won't he just be accessing stale information (that and the [read] doesn't encrypt anything it should just decrypt). Is there any chance of helping me understand this a bit further?